# openid in pylons (not using authkit)

Tags: python, openid, pylons, python-openid

So I'm trying to authenticate users on a Pylons web application using openid. I don't want to use authkit, seeing as it is no longer maintained.

I'm currently trying to use python-openid (available from git at http://github.com/openid/python-openid) and having a hard time with it. The pylons framework isn't making it easy for me to interact with the python-openid classes, which are basically looking for instances of python's HTTPServer and SimpleCookie classes...

Any assistance available? Has anyone solved this problem? TIA.

Answer (score 2):

OpenId with pylons through repoze.what works OK. Please see the following discussion in the pylons mailing list to find some pointers: http://groups.google.com/group/pylons-discuss/browse_thread/thread/162ebf131db3582b#